# Error "nothing to be done for x86_64_def" when trying to configure kernel

Tags: kernel

I am learning device drivers development from the book by John Madieu. The book tells me to run the command `make x86_64_def` to configure the kernel, but when I enter that in to the terminal, an error message shows up, saying `nothing to be done for x86_64_def`. The `x86_64_def` file is located in `linux/arch/x86/config`.

Comment: You haven't said what release you are talking about, however Ubuntu 14.04 LTS is EOL & off-topic, and Ubuntu 14.04 ESM is supported only by Canonical through Ubuntu Advantage and still off-topic (https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: sorry, I accidentally put the tag there. It was the irst thing that came up when I searched for "ubuntu".